The tense of the object clause in a subjunctive sentence
What is the difference in meaning between these sentences?

I would be lying if I said I am not interested.

I would be lying if I said I was not interested.

I would be lying if I said I were not interested.


I believe sentence 3 is correct if the speaker wants to show that 'I am not interested' is untrue.
Can sentence 2 mean that I must have been lying at the time if it's true that I said in the past that I was not interested?
Or in reality, do the three mean the same?

You're getting confused by the subjunctive. Sure, you can say If I were a rich man I'd buy it - subjunctive, same as If he were a rich man he'd buy it. But presumably you realize you can't say He would be lying if he said he were not interested. Cutting to the chase, #3 is not valid.

In almost all contexts, #1 and '2 are equivalent  - except #1 arguably shows "greater current interest", by virtue of the immediacy of Present Tense. Only in an unlikely / contrived scenario could there be a true difference in meaning (if, say, the context is focused on some time  in the past when I was very interested in something, but I'm no longer interested in it at time of speaking).

@FumbleFingers In the sentence 'I would be lying if I said I was not interested,' the phrase 'I would be lying if I said' is in the past subjunctive, showing a statement contrary to current fact. Since it refers to the present, wouldn't it be more logical to use 'I am not interested' instead of 'I was not interested,' as 'I was not interested' isn't subjunctive? Thank you for the comments.

Don't get too focused on the label "past subjunctive". It refers to a "timeless, unreal" situation. And it contrasts with what's called "present subjunctive" - but that isn't really, either. Present subjunctive (I suggest you go, He insists she be present) looks like the unmarked infinitive, but what it actually refers to is usually (always?) effectively a reference to a future action. But English subjunctive is a fading usage anyway, and many speakers (especially in conversational contexts) just use Simple Past in such contexts today.
